# Can't use hooks in FlatList renderItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

Please! Can somebody explain me whats wrong with following code. I'm trying to pass ListItem

```
export const ListItem: ListRenderItem<IUser> = ({item}) => {
 

  return (
    <RNEListItem onPress={() => {}}>
      <Avatar source={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}} rounded size="medium" />
      <RNEListItem.Content>
        <RNEListItem.Title>{`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}</RNEListItem.Title>
        <RNEListItem.Subtitle>{item.email}</RNEListItem.Subtitle>
      </RNEListItem.Content>
      <RNEListItem.Chevron size={30} />
    </RNEListItem>
  );
};
```

to renderItem prop in FlatList

```
return (
    <FlatList
      data={users}
      renderItem={ListItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListFooterComponent={ListLoader}
      onEndReached={handleMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      onRefresh={handleRefresh}
      refreshing={isRefreshing}
    />
  );
```

everything fine. But when I'm trying to use hooks

```
export const ListItem: ListRenderItem<IUser> = ({item}) => {
  const {navigate} = useNavigation<RootStackParamList>();

  const handlePress = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(item.login.uuid);
    navigate(ERootStackScreens.USER_SCREEN, {id: item.login.uuid});
  }, []);

  return (
    <RNEListItem onPress={() => {}}>
      <Avatar source={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}} rounded size="medium" />
      <RNEListItem.Content>
        <RNEListItem.Title>{`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}</RNEListItem.Title>
        <RNEListItem.Subtitle>{item.email}</RNEListItem.Subtitle>
      </RNEListItem.Content>
      <RNEListItem.Chevron size={30} />
    </RNEListItem>
  );
};
```

RN return's

```
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
```

but when i change renderItem this way

```
return (
    <FlatList
      data={users}
      renderItem={()=>ListItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ListFooterComponent={ListLoader}
      onEndReached={handleMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      onRefresh={handleRefresh}
      refreshing={isRefreshing}
    />
  );
```

Everything becomes fine. But it looks like types in docs are incorrect. Cuz according to them first example should work without problems

```
renderItem: ListRenderItem<ItemT> | null | undefined;


export type ListRenderItem<ItemT> = (info: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>) => React.ReactElement | null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the props in the functional component:

> renderItem={(props)=><ListItem {...props} />}

The problem you're encountering is related to a key rule in React: Hooks should always be used at the top level of your React functions. This means you can't put a hook inside a loop, condition, or nested function.

In your original code, when you do renderItem={ListItem}, you are treating ListItem as a callback function, not a React component. Even though it is written as a component, it doesn't act like one because it's not being used like a component.

In React, components have to be called in a certain context to allow hooks to work. This context is only provided if the function is used as a component, not as a callback.

Comment: But do you know why this is the case? So what specifically is wrong with just doing:
`renderItem={ListItem}`
(Meaning why doesn't it work on a technical level)

Comment: I updated the asnwer. Please flag it as answer if it fixed your error

Comment: Thanks! So if I did:
`const CallbackListItem = (props) => <ListItem {...props} />`
and
`renderItem={CallbackListItem}`
it works, because CallbackListItem is used, I imagine, in some sort of loop, where it returns a react component.
If I pass `ListItem` directly however, it is also called inside the loop but in this case it doesn't just return a component, it directly calls the function. When calling the function a hook is detected and an error is thrown.
Can't flag it as an answer since I didn't make the post, but it definitely answers the question